# insert and update from table a to table b by combining 2 column from table a in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables name Table A and Table B

"Table A has 10 columns named ta1, ta2, ta3...ta10"

"Table b has 2 columns name id (PK,AI) and tb1"

My requirement is to combine "ta3" and "ta4" from table A initially,
or it will check for the "tb1" column whether any same data is available, if available do nothing else insert the new data.(if a new row is added in the ta3 or ta4, it should be added to the 2nd table column named tb1)

I have checked other functions in the for combining the data from ta3 and ta4 by using the "unnest" function, but if I use that, I'm getting stuck in the insert, as it will insert on each query rather than checking whether any data is there or not.
any solution on this legends.

simply I just want to combine 2 column from 1st table and store it in a column on 2nd table, but in 2nd table's column it should be only distinct values taken from both of those 1st table columns. this should automatically check for the values in the column of 2nd table and compare that with the new one and if there is change the insert else neglect. I hope my question is clear.

[Table1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryME4.png)

[Table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTDrm.png)

[new table-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYIsc.png)

[Expected table-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyyiP.png)

Comment: Why do you have Tagged three different PostgreSQL versions [postgresql-9.3], [postgresql-9.4], [postgresql-9.5] w/o mentioning any particular version in the Question text?

Comment: any version will be okay , just to have more reach I used the same, I just needed to get the concept thats it, I hope you can help me on this @StefanWuebbe